Debugging LLDB with Swift fails to execute `po` command with couldn't IRGen expression: Clang importer error - missing OpenGL headers
I have an app that links ARKit.
Recently and totally randomly my ability to po ...some code... is gone with the following error:

error: couldn't IRGen expression: Clang importer error
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GLKit.framework/Headers/GLKEffectPropertyTexture.h:20:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_TEXTURE_2D'
GLKTextureTarget2D = GL_TEXTURE_2D,
^


error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/GLKit.framework/Headers/GLKEffectPropertyTexture.h:21:31: error: use of undeclared identifier 'GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP'
GLKTextureTargetCubeMap = GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP,
^
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SceneKit.framework/Headers/SceneKitTypes.h:34:9: error: could not build module 'GLKit'
#import <GLKit/GLKMathTypes.h>
^


error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ARKit.framework/Headers/ARFaceGeometry.h:9:9: error: could not build module 'SceneKit'
#import <SceneKit/SCNGeometry.h>
^


error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SpriteKit.framework/Headers/SKUniform.h:15:9: error: could not build module 'GLKit'
#import <GLKit/GLKMath.h>
^

I tried deleting derived data, cleaning out clang modulecache, cleaning build folder, reinstalling xcode.
It works in some other projects and on another machine, but not on mine which is incredibly frustrating.
OpenGL and OpenGLES frameworks are present on my machine so should be working fine?
UPDATE I have found that when this happens if I first add
expr import GLKit; import SceneKit;

Then I get an error like so:
warning: Swift error in fallback scratch context: error while processing module import: error: could not build Objective-C module 'GLKit'
note: This error message is displayed only once. If the error displayed above is due to conflicting search paths to Clang modules in different images of the debugged executable, this can slow down debugging of Swift code significantly, since a fresh Swift context has to be created every time a conflict is encountered.
  Fix-it applied, fixed expression was: 
    import GLKit; import SceneKit

But then my po is back
